# Undoing a merge in Git - after doing a git reset --merge?

Tags: git

I did a merge from a feature branch to master.  But then I wanted to undo the merge, so did this:

```
git reset --merge xxxxx
```

But...now what?  Do I do a git push or something to actually have the undo merge happen on the server?  I think maybe all I did was undo the merge on my local copy?

Comment: Please note that the vast majority of commands only affect the local repo, except pull, push, and fetch (that I know of)

Comment: @evolutionxbox Clone (which is init + fetch + checkout), `ls-remote`, `remote`.